# How to get recent posts from wordpress RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I tried to find a way to get the latest/recent posts that published on my website, but the Rss feed seems to be Sorted alphabetically,  
 so its not show the recent posts and make the feed rss kind of useless. 
i find that it possible to change pages using /feed/?paged= but its not help me in my case 

i need to find a way to sort the feed rss by recent posts 
thanks

Comment: if your RSS feed is sorted alphabetically that implies that there is a `pre_get_posts` filter interfering with sorting that hasn't been implemented properly. RSS is chronological by default already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i tried a lot until i tried

```
feed/?orderby=latest
```

it seem to work, hope it help other